# How can I correct the error with password verify in my code

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a log in form. But every time that I try to login it always give a error message that my password is incorrect. Im using md5 to hash my password in the database.

I've tried to remove the hash and password_verify to my code but it automatically login the user with incorrect passowrd

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {

require 'dbh.inc.php';

$mailuid = $_POST['mailuid'];
$password = $_POST['pwd'];

if (empty($mailuid) || empty($password)){
    header("Location: ../systemlogintut/index1.php?error=emptyfields");
    exit(); 
}
else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=? OR emailUsers=?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: ../systemlogintut/index1.php?error=sqlerror");
    exit(); 
    }
    else {

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $password);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);
            if ($pwdCheck == false) {
            header("Location: ../systemlogintut/index1.php?error=wrongpwd");
            exit();     
            }
            else if ($pwdCheck == true) {
                session_start();
                $_SERVER['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
                $_SERVER['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];
                header("Location: ../systemlogintut/index1.php?login=success");
            exit();
            }
            else {
            header("Location: ../systemlogintut/index1.php?error=wrongpwd");
            exit();
            }
        }
        else {
            header("Location: ../systemlogintut/index1.php?error=nouser");
            exit(); 
        }
    }
  }
}
else {
  header("Location: ../systemlogintut/index1.php");
  exit();
}
```

Comment: _"Im using mb5 to hash my password"_ - If you're using md5() when hashing them (which you shouldn't be doing since md5 is _not_ a secure hash), you can't use `password_verify()` to validate the hash. That function is for checking hashes made with `password_hash()` (which is what you should be using instead).

Comment: if you are using md5 to store your password in db, then you need to convert your password to md5 before the query

Comment: Btw, your query is odd. You have this `WHERE uidUsers=? OR emailUsers=?` but you're binding `$mailuid, $password`?

Comment: I just change it. Now its running fine. Thanks Everyone!

Comment: @pogapogipogi - If you got the code working, write an answer explaining what you did so future visitors might benefit from your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are automatically logging in the user, change the redirect code in this line

```
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
   $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);
     if ($pwdCheck == false) {
        header("Location: ../systemlogintut/index1.php?error=wrongpwd"); // change the redirection here
     exit();     
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between this code and the original code and how would your suggested change solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just change it to:

```
$hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

instead of using:

```
$hashedPwd = mb5($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: It's `md5()`, not `mb5()`

Answer (score 0):

try it
$password = md5($_POST['pwd']);